# Can shared object be built from from archive of object files compiled without PIC option?

Tags: object, gcc, archive, shared

I have archives which are compiled with out -fPIC option.
Can we build a shared library from archives.

I am not able to do this using gcc 3.

Do newer versions of gcc support this thing?

Answer (score 0):

No...relocatable code can be generated only from PIC code.